# Is there a difference in the performace between using average in window function and count the avg first and use join

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 8.0
Table NameL: sc (score)
Columns: student_id, course_id, score
Some dummy data:

```
create table sc(SId varchar(10),CId varchar(10),score decimal(18,1));
insert into sc values('01' , '01' , 80);
insert into sc values('01' , '02' , 90);
insert into sc values('01' , '03' , 99);
insert into sc values('02' , '01' , 70);
insert into sc values('02' , '02' , 60);
insert into sc values('02' , '03' , 80);
insert into sc values('03' , '01' , 80);
insert into sc values('03' , '02' , 80);
insert into sc values('03' , '03' , 80);
insert into sc values('04' , '01' , 50);
insert into sc values('04' , '02' , 30);
insert into sc values('04' , '03' , 20);
insert into sc values('05' , '01' , 76);
insert into sc values('05' , '02' , 87);
insert into sc values('06' , '01' , 31);
insert into sc values('06' , '03' , 34);
insert into sc values('07' , '02' , 89);
insert into sc values('07' , '03' , 98);
```

The question is: **Output all the scores and the average scores of each student, and order the results in descending order of average score.**

I came up with two solutions:

```
-- Solution 1
SELECT
  sc.*,
  AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY sid) AS avg_score
FROM sc
ORDER BY avg_score DESC
```

```
-- Solution 2
select *  from sc 
left join (
    select sid,avg(score) as avscore from sc 
    group by sid
    )r 
on sc.sid = r.sid
order by avscore desc;
```

#### But is there a difference in the performance of the efficiency of these two solutions if the table is really big?

Here's the screenshot of EXPLAIN for these two queries:
[image]

Comment: the easiest way to find out is running benchmarks on your own. see the benchmark function in mysql

Comment: There are no indexes on your table? When looking at performance indexes are the first thing to consider and you should also run EXPLAIN to see what optimiser thinks it's doing as well as benchmarking.

Comment: @Psi I chekced the manual for BENCHMARK(). But it says `Only scalar expressions can be used`. Can you be more specific on how to get the running time of my queries please?  Thanks!

Comment: Let me phrase it that way: You can define your own stored function returning a scalar but executing your sql inside...

Comment: @Psi If I understand you correctly, you were saying I should do `BENCHMARK(1000, (mysql))` right? But it says in the manual that **For example, BENCHMARK(10, (SELECT * FROM t)) fails if the table t has more than one column or more than one row.** Also, as it suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752833/benchmark-function-in-mysql-incredible-results, BENCHMARK is not a for testing query runtime. Again, thank you for your reply!

Comment: no, create function… containing your select and call that one. and implicitly it does test the query runtime. just make sure you use the SQL_NO_CACHE hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a technique for checking performance when you only have a small subset of the data:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

-- Solution 1

```
mysql> flush status;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   sc.*,
    ->   AVG(score) OVER (PARTITION BY sid) AS avg_score
    -> FROM sc
    -> ORDER BY avg_score DESC;
+------+------+-------+-----------+
| sid  | cid  | score | avg_score |
+------+------+-------+-----------+
| 07   | 03   |  98.0 |  93.50000 |
| 07   | 02   |  89.0 |  93.50000 |
| 01   | 03   |  99.0 |  89.66667 |
| 01   | 01   |  80.0 |  89.66667 |
| 01   | 02   |  90.0 |  89.66667 |
| 05   | 01   |  76.0 |  81.50000 |
| 05   | 02   |  87.0 |  81.50000 |
| 03   | 01   |  80.0 |  80.00000 |
| 03   | 02   |  80.0 |  80.00000 |
| 03   | 03   |  80.0 |  80.00000 |
| 02   | 01   |  70.0 |  70.00000 |
| 02   | 02   |  60.0 |  70.00000 |
| 02   | 03   |  80.0 |  70.00000 |
| 04   | 01   |  50.0 |  33.33333 |
| 04   | 03   |  20.0 |  33.33333 |
| 04   | 02   |  30.0 |  33.33333 |
| 06   | 01   |  31.0 |  32.50000 |
| 06   | 03   |  34.0 |  32.50000 |
+------+------+-------+-----------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Handlers:

```
mysql> show session status like 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 2     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 1     |
| Handler_read_key           | 1     |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 0     |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 36    |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 60    |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 36    |
+----------------------------+-------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

-- Solution 2

```
mysql> flush status;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *  from sc 
    -> left join (
    ->     select sid,avg(score) as avscore from sc 
    ->     group by sid
    ->     )r 
    -> on sc.sid = r.sid
    -> order by avscore desc;
+------+------+-------+------+----------+
| sid  | cid  | score | sid  | avscore  |
+------+------+-------+------+----------+
| 07   | 03   |  98.0 | 07   | 93.50000 |
| 07   | 02   |  89.0 | 07   | 93.50000 |
| 01   | 02   |  90.0 | 01   | 89.66667 |
| 01   | 03   |  99.0 | 01   | 89.66667 |
| 01   | 01   |  80.0 | 01   | 89.66667 |
| 05   | 01   |  76.0 | 05   | 81.50000 |
| 05   | 02   |  87.0 | 05   | 81.50000 |
| 03   | 01   |  80.0 | 03   | 80.00000 |
| 03   | 02   |  80.0 | 03   | 80.00000 |
| 03   | 03   |  80.0 | 03   | 80.00000 |
| 02   | 01   |  70.0 | 02   | 70.00000 |
| 02   | 02   |  60.0 | 02   | 70.00000 |
| 02   | 03   |  80.0 | 02   | 70.00000 |
| 04   | 01   |  50.0 | 04   | 33.33333 |
| 04   | 02   |  30.0 | 04   | 33.33333 |
| 04   | 03   |  20.0 | 04   | 33.33333 |
| 06   | 01   |  31.0 | 06   | 32.50000 |
| 06   | 03   |  34.0 | 06   | 32.50000 |
+------+------+-------+------+----------+
18 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Handlers:

```
mysql> show session status like 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 4     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 2     |
| Handler_read_key           | 20    |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 36    |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 19    |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 7     |
+----------------------------+-------+
18 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I deduce that the `OVER` approach is twice as slow.

Windowing functions are useful in some situations where there is essentially no other way to achieve a goal, but I have not found them to be faster when there is an alternative.

Comment: This is such a thorough answer. The function you used is new to me. Is there any book or resource I can refer to when it comes to the performance? Thank you!

Comment: @ericzheng0404 - Yeah, come to me.  Seriously, ...  There are 3 _different_ books entitled "High Performance MySQL".  (I don't know if any of them mention my "Handlers%" trick.)  My performance blog is HTTP://mysql.rjweb.org .  That technique is mentioned in my [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to the table, it is likely that Solution 2 might shine:

```
INDEX(sid, score)
```

I did a small test using your data and queries, but came up with an indeterminate result.  (I checked the session status 'Handler%' values.)

I prefer this variation of 2:

select *
FROM  (
select sid,avg(score) as avscore from sc
group by sid
) AS r
JOIN sc USING(sid)
order by avscore desc;

Suggest you try with a million rows.

Comment: I tried EXPLAIN for both the queries, and it seems that the first query has fewer rows and steps than the second one. Are these two a good indicator of efficiency in this context? Thank you!

Comment: @ericzheng0404 - Don't read too much into `EXPLAIN`.  The "Rows" is an estimate, sometimes it is a poor estimate.  Show us the `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: Appended a screenshot

Comment: @ericzheng0404 - When there are a million rows, you won't want a million lines of output.  Rethink the goal of the query; then we can discuss performance issues.